# paypal IPN initialization

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to build a form in which a user selects one of two pre-defined subscription packages (And they are also already setup on my paypal account), and when they select one and submit the form, it directs them to the correct paypal subscription registration page. I have tried checking the documentation to see how the POST needs to be assembled so when the form is submitted it directs them to the correct page, but I am unable to find any documentation pertaining to this step.

i already have my IPN listener implemented and working (as tested on the ipn test tool and the sandbox), but I can't seem to find any documentation pertaining to how to assemble the URL to send the user to when they submit the form.

(For example, from a 'button maker' tool on the paypal site, I got this link:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=MP6PZTT

But, I can't find in the documentation anywhere where that's assembled, and what MP6PZTT refers to in the paypal account.

Is there anyone that can give me some information on how the URL needs to be assembled so that when the user selects a button than submits the form, it puts the correct information in the URL for that subscription.

Comment: It's the button ID for the button you generated with the tool.

Comment: Right but how can I use it for a link instead of a button ? I suppose I could Judy link it in an href but doesn't it need to be passed via post with other data ?

Comment: Rather, let me rephrase the question. Right now, I am using it in a link like <a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=MP6PZTT&notify_url=http://example.com/notify.php"> which redirects to the paypal sandbox and the correct subscription is shown, but after you accept it and the subscription starts, it doesnt send any information to my IPN listener. I've used the IPN test tool on paypals developer site and my listener works, but for some reason this method doesnt send an IPN message even with IPN enabled.

Comment: Do you have a notify_url defined in your account? Or in the parameters for this link?